# Nested Dicts with Lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to build a dict with lists as values, which contain dicts with lists as values:

```
xml_dict = { 
'Spain':['La Palma':[2929, ..], 'Fuerteventura':[5733, ..]],
'Turkey':['Antalya':[16483, ..], 'Izmir':[2927, ...]] 
... }
```

My starting basis is a list with dicts:

```
self.db_data_list = [
{'land': 'Spain', 'giatahotelcode': 2929, 'zielgebiet_abweichung': 'La Palma'},
{'land': 'Spain', 'giatahotelcode': 5733, 'zielgebiet_abweichung': 'Fuerteventura'}, 
{'land': 'Turkey', 'giatahotelcode': 16483, 'zielgebiet_abweichung': 'Antalya'},
{'land': 'Turkey', 'giatahotelcode': 2927, 'zielgebiet_abweichung': 'Izmir'}
```

And here's my code so far:

```
zg_giata_dict = dict()
country_zg_dict = dict()
xml_dict = dict()

countries = [ value for data_dict in self.db_data_list for key, value in data_dict.iteritems() if key == 'land' ]
countries = set(countries)

zgs = [ value for data_dict in self.db_data_list for key, value in data_dict.iteritems() if key == 'zielgebiet_abweichung' ]
zgs = set(zgs)

for data_dict in self.db_data_list:
    for country in countries:
        if data_dict['land'] == country:
            country_zg_dict.setdefault(country, []).append(data_dict['zielgebiet_abweichung'])
            country_zg_dict[country] = list(set(country_zg_dict[country])) 

for data_dict in self.db_data_list:
    for zg in zgs:
        if data_dict['zielgebiet_abweichung'] == zg: 
            zg_giata_dict.setdefault(zg, []).append(data_dict['giatahotelcode'])

for country, zg_list in country_zg_dict.iteritems():
    for zg, giata_list in zg_giata_dict.iteritems():
        if zg in zg_list:
            xml_dict.setdefault(country, []).append(giata_list)
```

Output xml_dict:

```
{'Spain': [[2929, ...], [5733, ...]], 'Turkey': [[16483, ...], [2927, ...]], ... }
```

My output is not bad at all - but I miss the values from `zielgebiet_abweichung` (self.db_data_list) in my `xml_dict`. I have no idea how to manage that. Any ideas?

Comment: Your intended output -- `{ 
'Spain':['La Palma':[2929, ..], 'Fuerteventura':[5733, ..]],
'Turkey':['Antalya':[16483, ..], 'Izmir':[2927, ...]] 
... }` -- is not a valid dictionary or list

Comment: Sorry, my fault: `xml_dict = { 
'Spain':[{'La Palma':[2929, ..}], 'Fuerteventura':[{5733, ..]}],
'Turkey':[{'Antalya':[16483, ..], 'Izmir':[2927, ...]}] 
... }`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. Isn't want you want just a nested dictionary, like `{'Spain': {'La Palma': [2929, ...], 'Fuerteventura': [5733, ...]}, 'Turkey': {'Antalya': [16483, ...], 'Izmir': [2927, ...]}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you actually need is a dictionary with dictionaries as values, where those inner dictionaries have lists as values.

```
for hotel in self.db_data_list:
    land = hotel['land']
    town = hotel['zielgebiet_abweichung']
    code = hotel['giatahotelcode']
    if land in all_data:
        if town in all_data[land]:
            all_data[land][town].append(code)
        else:
            all_data[land][town] = [code]
    else:
        all_data[land] = {town: [code]}
```

This returns:

```
{'Turkey': {'Antalya': [16483], 'Izmir': [2927]}, 
 'Spain': {'Fuerteventura': [5733], 'La Palma': [2929]}}
```

You can also use `setdefault` to do the same thing:

```
all_data = {}
for hotel in self.db_data_list:
    land = all_data.setdefault(hotel['land'], {})
    town = land.setdefault(hotel['zielgebiet_abweichung'], [])
    town.append(hotel['giatahotelcode'])
```

Comment: Hmpf, this works fine.. But I dont get it anyway: `town = land.setdefault(hotel['zielgebiet_abweichung'], [])` In my opinion this line would overwrite the key from the land-dict. Could you explain this line? For example: When I print land or town before appending the codes, they're only an empty dict and a list. Thank you very much btw.!

Comment: `list.setdefault(key, default)` returns the value associated with `key` if it is in the dictionary, or if not creates the key and sets its value to `default`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault